# blueimg image upload directory and getting the uploaded image name

Tags: php, blueimp

I am trying to use blueimg image uploader in my webpage(in php), however I am having trouble with upload directories. here is the path of my files.

the start page is index.php which is in blueimg folder and all other required blueimg files and folders are in that blueimg folder.

Here are the lines in upload.class.php

```
        'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
        'param_name' => 'files',
```

Do I need to modify any other lines in any other file?

And the second question: I am wondering is there any way to get the name of uploaded image's name in order to save into database?

Comment: What exact problems are you having? Also, perhaps use `__FILE__` instead of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`

Comment: I also tried it but when I try to upload the image an error sign appears on the page. Seems like the problem is in the directory and url definition I stated above, but could not find it out.

Comment: I just realize that there could be a problem on the permissions of the upload folder and I did chmod 777 on my folder and it worked.